# Solving a second-order non-linear ODE (In search of an easier way)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(1+x^2)y'' + 1+y'^2=0$$

What I did was:

$y'=z, z(x)$

After substituting and dividing by $1+x^2$ I get that $$z' = -\frac{z^2+1}{x^2+1}$$

Which is a separable equation, the solution for which is $$z=\tan({c_1 - \arctan{x}})$$

However, when I undo the substitution I get that

$$ y=\int{\tan{(c_1 - \arctan{x}}})dx $$

which isn't as easy to solve as I thought it would be, and the result is not pretty.

Is there an easier way to solve it?

Comment: Note that $\tan(c-\arctan x)=\frac{A-x}{1+Ax}$.

Comment: @user10354138 What's that? I'm not following

Comment: It is the formula for the sum of angles: $\tan(x\pm y) = \dfrac{\tan(x)\pm \tan(y)}{1 \mp \tan(x)\tan(y)}$

Comment: @johndoe: Did you complete this problem?

Comment: @johndoe: Since my solution didn't seem helpful to you, I have deleted it.